# Img nor backgroundImage doesn't repeat in thead in FireFox 25 in printing mode

Tags: html, css, image

I Have a table with a thead include a couple of div, when i remove div with img, it works correctly but when i add the img to one of the them, it doesn't repeat per page in printing mode, i also add background image to dive instead img, still not working, and also background image to th tah, still not working! 
my code is as below:

```
<thead style="border:0;">
<tr>
<th colspan="8" >
<div  align="right" style="display:inline-block; 
background-image:url(http://persiacala.com/cache/fck_files/image/logo.png); 
background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:right; text-align:right;
width:1200px; he text-align=right; height:190px;">
</div>
<div class="nochangeLang" align="left" style="border-bottom:solid 1px; 
margin-left:50px; margin-right:250px; text-align:center; 
font-family:Aharoni;    font-size:14pt; " >            
ProFoma Invoice No :$شماره پيش 
</div>
<div align="left" class="nochangeLang" style="padding-bottom:9px;
margin-left:50px; text-align:left; font-family: Aharoni; 
font-size:12pt;">    
Date:$DateDigit$                                                          
</div>
<div class="nochangeLang" align="left" style="font-family: Aharoni; 
font-size: 11pt; text-align:left;">                                                
TO:$CompanyNameRequester$                                                         
</div>
<div align="left" style="font-family: Aharoni; 
font-size: 11pt; text-align:left;">                
Att:$PersonNameRequester$                                                             
</div>
<div align="left" style="font-family: Aharoni; font-size: 11pt; text-align:left;">
Ref No:$RefNo$ Requsted DD.:$RequestedDD$
</div>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Also i add this css to my css sheet:

```
thead {
display:table-header-group;
}
```

still not working, and just when i remove img, it works!
thanks for help.

Comment: First, you have errors in your CSS, such as `he text-align=right;`. Check those. Also, one div has `align="left"` and a contradictory style of `text-align:center`. Also, can you make a fiddle or something? Your current source is not large enough to print over multiple pages.

Comment: in my computer it works, but in cutstomer pc, doesn't work, is there eny config for ff to prevent repeating header?

Comment: I read somewhere that if the `thead` is "too high", it will not be repeated in subsequent pages. However, I don't know how high "too high" is. And if it seems to depend on the computer (or maybe on the paper size) that is difficult to debug. You can start by making the content of the `thead` higher (by duplicating the `th` or something) and see if it stops working on your computer. Then at least you'll know it has to do with the height.

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes the problem is exactly related to height.

Comment: Then make the logo smaller, try to fit the different texts on one line, or take some of the info out of the `thead` and put it in the `tbody`. By the way, the logo is better off as an `<img>` than a `background-image`. Not all browsers support printing background graphics.

Comment: I maked div height smaller an worked, thanks for your hand Mr Lister.

Answer (score 0):

I added height to all the div and limited their height by 20 px, then FF acts as i expect.